# Is there any way to calculate the roots of this polynom?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, polynomials

I need to calculate the roots of the real function $f$:
$$
f(x)=\frac{-{x}^{3}+2{x}^{2}+4}{{x}^{2}}
$$
But I am not able to decompose the numerator. There should be only one real solution and two complex, and I tryed to aproximate it using the Bolzano's Theorem, so I know that the root must be between 2.6 and 2.605, but that's all I got...

Comment: Try use Cardano's algorithm. Essentially, you are just finding the roots of a cubic equation.

Comment: How do you get $2.6$? The real root is $2$...

Comment: In general there is a closed form expression for roots of cubics but they do get messy.  Read [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots).

Comment: Using the formula for the root of a cubic you get $(2+(62-6\sqrt{105})^{1/3}+(62+6\sqrt{105})^{1/3})/3\approx2.5943130163548487449$ for the real root.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Newton's method to find a zero of $f$. Choose any $x_0$ and define the sequence: $x_{n+1}= x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$. It converges to a root of the function (under some assumptions that you don't really care  about when the function is a polynomial)

Answer (score 0):

First we know that the domain of $f$ is $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$. Since $f$ is defined as a quotient of polynomials, we know that $f=0$ when the numerator is $0$. Thus we solve
$$-x^3+x^2+4=0.$$
We can find the roots to this polynomial using WolframAlpha or Mathematica.

Comment: Sorry, I commit a mistake writing the function

Answer (score 0):

We need: $-x^3+2x^2+4 = 0$, but as you noted, you can't further reduce this polynomial in order to find it's roots. In this case you find away to approximate the roots.